# How can I list items created with the float package in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I created a new type of float using the `float` package.

```
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{recommendation}{htbp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{recommendation}{Recommendation}
```

I would like it listed in the ToC as List of Recommendations.

I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want to list in the ToC, the "List of Recommendations" or each one of the recommendations?

Answer (score 7):

Simply adding `\addcontensline` after `\listof` will produce incorrect page numbering in the ToC if the List of Recommendations spans several pages. Instead, I suggest to redefine `\float@listhead`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{recommendation}{htbp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{recommendation}{Recommendation}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\float@listhead}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  }{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  }%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listof{recommendation}{List of Recommendations}

\section{foo}

\begin{recommendation}
A recommendation.
\caption{Use \LaTeX!}
\end{recommendation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the `book` class one can simply say `\renewcommand\float@listhead[1]{\chapter{#1}}`, if the lists are to be typeset in the `\frontmatter` or in the `\backmatter`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that (i) you're using the `article` document class and (ii) you're OK with having the List of Recommendations look like the List of Tables and the List of Figures, the following should work for you. Note that

- the "List of Recommendations" is generated by the command `\listofrecs` and that
- each recommendation float is created by `\begin{rec}` ... `\end{rec}`.

Two additional comments. First, if you want to write out `recommendation` instead of `rec`, just change the first argument of the `newfloat` and `\floatname` macros from `rec` to `recommendation`. Second, if you're using the `book` (`report`) document class rather than the `article` document class, just look for the definition of `\listoffigures` in `book.cls` (`report.cls`) and (i) copy that code into your preamble and (ii) replace `figure` with `rec` throughout. (Of course, that's what I did for the case of the `article` document class in the MWE below...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{rec}{htbp}{lor}[section]  % 'lor' is short for "List of Recommendations"
\floatname{rec}{Recommendation}

\makeatletter
% the following is adapted from the definition of the "List of Tables" in article.cls
\newcommand{\listrecname}{List of Recommendations}
\newcommand\listofrecs{%
    \section*{\listrecname}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listrecname}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listrecname}%
    \@starttoc{lor}%
    }
\let\l@rec\l@figure
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listofrecs

\section{Some recommendations}
\begin{rec}
\caption{Go away}\label{rec:1}
\end{rec}
\begin{rec}
\caption{No, stay}\label{rec:2}
\end{rec}
\begin{rec}
\caption{Come back!}\label{rec:3}
\end{rec}
\end{document}
```

[image]